# How can I integrate private icons into the system's icon selector (Kubuntu)?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, icons, dialog

I've got loads of private icons (*.png, *.svg, *.ico) which I'm using for my diverse special topic folders on my local systems (Windows & Ubuntu) and so I need to store them in its own tree (*with a topical subfolder hierarchy*) that is available for all systems and from a non-system partition.

This works fine for general icon management and also on the Windows side, but it's a clicker mess (*at least 8 clicks!*) on (K)Ubuntu to change a folder icon.

Now, I could use a workaround with a service menu that calls a simple file picker, but that's not very nice as I still want to have parallel access – *with as few clicks as possible* – to the system icons which I'm using also.
Therefore the easiest usability way would be to somehow integrate (*e.g. folder link*) my private icon tree into the systems icon selector (*in my case KDE 4 & 5*) – ideally *without* reordering my private topic hierarchy to the Ubuntu size hierarchy, as this would break up all my folder icons over a vast range of folders and on two platforms.

Is that possible and if so, how can I manage that?

Comment: The [Icon Theme Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/icon-theme-spec/icon-theme-spec-latest.html) might help.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this link. This should be the information I was looking for, though it seems to be more complicated to implement my plan than expected.